# Optional chaining to add a "data-attribute" on PugJS

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, pug, pug-loader

I am looking for a solution to add "optional chaining" on PugJS to set `data-active="true"` if `i === 0`.

Bellow is my current code. This code is working, but the problem with this approach (bellow) is that I have to repeat my code on a `else` statement and that doesn't make sense. I have to add `(i === 0 ? 'data-active="true"' : '')` on the `.my__element`, but I don't know how to do it.

```js
if (i === 0)
  .my__element(data-month=months[month] data-active="true")
else
  .my__element(data-month=months[month])
```

Any help please? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attribute values in Pug are "just regular JavaScript," as mentioned on the [*Attributes* page on Pug docs](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html).

If an attribute's value is `false`, Pug doesn't print the attribute at all. This can be seen in the [*Boolean Attributes* section on the same page](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#boolean-attributes):

```html
// Input (Pug):
input(type='checkbox' checked)
input(type='checkbox' checked=true)
input(type='checkbox' checked=false)
input(type='checkbox' checked="true")

// Output (HTML):
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="true" />
```

So, you can use `i === 0 && "true"` as the value for the `data-active` attribute:

```
.my__element(data-month=months[month] data-active=(i === 0 && "true"))
```

The parentheses around the attribute's value are optional, but they improve readability. So this is OK but less readable:

```
.my__element(data-month=months[month] data-active=i === 0 && "true")
```

A more verbose alternative:

```
.my__element(data-month=months[month] data-active=(i === 0 ? "true" : false))
.my__element(data-month=months[month] data-active=i === 0 ? "true" : false)
```

(Note that `"true"` is a string and `false` is a boolean; this is on purpose. You can try to switch their types to see why.)

Comment: I've to say sometimes I go on the PugJS docs and it's hard to find exactly what we need. I see we have to look to the docs with a more surgical eye. Thank you for the whole explanation and for giving the "A more verbose alternative" example.